# How to set dilation rate for atrous convolution dynamically in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, while-loop

I'm writing a custom recurrent neural network. The network state is defined in the body of a while loop and the recursion stops when a certain condition occurs.  I'd like to use the number of iterations as a parameter for some functions inside the loop. For example when I use atrous convolutions I'd want the rate of dilation to depend on the current iteration.

```
def body(self,..., iteration):
    dilation_rate = 2**iteration
    state = tf.nn.atrous_conv2d(..., rate = dilation_rate)
    iteration += 1

def RNN_loop(...)
    iter = tf.constant(np.array(0), dtype = tf.int32)
    ... = tf.while_loop(self.condition, self.body, [...,iter])
```

Because iteration is defined as a tensor I don't know how to pass it to the atrous_conv2d which expect a number. If I try to evaluate the value of the tensor inside the loop with iteration.eval I get:

```
ValueError: Operation u'layer/while/Identity_4' has been marked as not fetchable.
```

If I pass the tensor to the function I get:

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Comment: Most attributes like this accept a tensor and probably just convert a numeric value into a `tf.constant` for you automatically. Have you tried passing a tensor into `atrous_conv2d`? There are exceptions, and if `atrous_conv2d` doesn't support a tensor then you're probably stuck with posting a feature (dare I say bug) request on github.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR**: use [`tf.nn.convolution()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/convolution) instead of [`tf.nn.atrous_conv2d()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/atrous_conv2d) and short-circuit `tf.nn._nn_ops._get_strides_and_dilation_rate()`. (See code sample at the bottom of the answer.)

---

**TS;WM**:

The implementation of [`tf.nn.atrous_conv2d()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/atrous_conv2d) basically just calls [`tf.nn.convolution()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/convolution) with the `dilation_rate` set to `[rate, rate]`. [This](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.8/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py#L1043) is the current position in the source, but I'm copying it here (without 130 lines of comments) because it might change so the link might get outdated:

```py
def atrous_conv2d(value, filters, rate, padding, name=None):
    return convolution(
        input=value,
        filter=filters,
        padding=padding,
        dilation_rate=np.broadcast_to(rate, (2,)),
        name=name)
```

Here it's clear that the `np.broadcast_to()` makes it impossible to use a tensor for the `dilation_rate`. Maybe in `tf.nn.convolution()` then?

Well, theoretically, yes, up until the call to `_get_strides_and_dilation_rate()` which most unhelpfully has things like

```py
dilation_rate = np.array(dilation_rate, dtype=np.int32)
```

After that, the `Convolution` class doesn't care much and the `_WithSpaceToBatch.__init__()` ends up explicitly converting it to tensor right away:

```py
dilation_rate = ops.convert_to_tensor(
    dilation_rate, dtypes.int32, name="dilation_rate")
```

So if you're super confident that your parameters are all right, you can then short-circuit `tf.nn._get_strides_and_dilation_rate()` and then call `tf.nn.convolution()` directly with a two-dim dilation rate, like this code (tested):

```py
import tensorflow as tf

square_size = 5
dr = tf.placeholder( shape = ( 2, ), dtype = tf.int32 )
inp = tf.reshape( tf.constant( range( square_size * square_size ), dtype = tf.float32 ), ( 1, square_size, square_size, 1 ) )
fltr = tf.reshape( tf.ones( ( 3, 3 ) ), ( 3, 3, 1, 1 ))

_original = tf.nn._nn_ops._get_strides_and_dilation_rate
tf.nn._nn_ops._get_strides_and_dilation_rate = lambda a, b, c : ( b, c )
state = tf.nn.convolution( inp, fltr, "SAME", strides = [ 1, 1 ], dilation_rate = dr )
tf.nn._nn_ops._get_strides_and_dilation_rate = _original

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print( sess.run( tf.squeeze( inp ) ) )
    print
    print( sess.run( tf.squeeze( state ), feed_dict = { dr : [ 2, 2 ] } ) )
    print
    print( sess.run( tf.squeeze( state ), feed_dict = { dr : [ 3, 3 ] } ) )
```

will output the results with dynamically changed dilation rate (the `tf.squeeze`s are for legibility only):

> [[ 0.  1.  2.  3.  4.]
>    [ 5.  6.  7.  8.  9.]
>    [10. 11. 12. 13. 14.]
>    [15. 16. 17. 18. 19.]
>    [20. 21. 22. 23. 24.]]
>
> [[ 24.  28.  42.  28.  32.]
>    [ 44.  48.  72.  48.  52.]
>    [ 66.  72. 108.  72.  78.]
>    [ 44.  48.  72.  48.  52.]
>    [ 64.  68. 102.  68.  72.]]
>
> [[36. 40. 19. 36. 40.]
>    [56. 60. 29. 56. 60.]
>    [23. 25. 12. 23. 25.]
>    [36. 40. 19. 36. 40.]
>    [56. 60. 29. 56. 60.]]